# CRUD operations template in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, crud

I'm designing a system where I must perform several CRUD operations among the System entities. Just for make sure I searched in forums to see how it's resolved by someone else.

I found 4 *"patterns"*. All of them agree in the READ operations so I skip them. I'll define the patterns:

#### Pattern 1

```
void add(E entity);
void update(E entity);
// Read operations...
void delete(E entity);
```

#### Pattern 2

```
E create(<ListOfEntityProperties>);
void update(E entity);
// Read operations...
void delete(E entity);
```

#### Pattern 3

```
boolean add(E entity);
boolean update(E entity);
// Read operations...
boolean delete(E entity);
```

#### Pattern 4

```
E add(E entity);
void update(E entity);
// Read operations...
void delete(E entity);
```

I don't understand the difference and advantages/disadvantages of each one (and no one explains it). What are the differences between each *"pattern"*? What criteria to use? Can someone justify when to use one way or another (or give me another idea)?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: The answer to this depends on what you need, and is mostly opinion based. There is no "one" pattern, and I've seen a combination of these.

Comment: That's something, can you say when to use each one? I think that if you have a specific need, there's no worth opinion. The thing is that I don't realize what criteria to have in mind to choose between one or other. Do you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take Pattern 3, for example, you'd use a boolean to know if something successfully was deleted or added. The deleted case is okay, but for the added or updated case, you might want the object back with a database assigned id, which looks like pattern 4.

If you want to batch insert objects, then that's pattern 2.

And if you don't expect to return anything from a CRUD operation, then make the methods `void`.

The values that you want returned are the important part, the "patterns" don't matter so much, and they completely depend on the underlying API usage. For example, a SQL Server insert operation may return the row ID of the inserted object. In that case, you could return just the ID, or the same object you passed as a parameter, but with its ID field set.

Comment: Thank you so much, those are good criteria. Just to add something, I've just watching the Spring's [CrudRepository Interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) and uses something like the **Pattern 4**: `E save(E entity); void delete(E entity)`, where `save()` is for adding and updating (or at least I understand it that way)

Answer (score 0):

Jut asking , why do you want to write\design your own implementations.
I used java-ee annotation for this.

references:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/package-summary.html
http://www.techferry.com/articles/RESTful-web-services-JAX-RS-annotations.html

You can refer their implementations too.

Comment: I'm not creating services in this app to consume with a frontend (like Angular.js or something else), I'm expecting this methods to be a simple call to the Hibernate's API, as I'm using this framework for persistence. I saw some tutorials and different persistence methods signatures were used, so the doubt came to me, do you know what I mean? Hope that answers your question